# Checkout directly in Credit Card and disable the email and password input

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using PayPal express checkout to ensure users pay directly by credit card on a landing page, but there are 2 fields I wish to remove, that is 'email' and 'password, I tried to insert the code below:

```
'METHOD'=> 'SetExpressCheckout',
'LANDINGPAGE' => 'Billing',
'BUYEREMAILOPTINENABLE' => 0,
```

For some reason even after I disable `BUYEREMAILOPTINENABLE`, the fields still appear. I can't make them disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing Express Checkout with [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/). Express Checkout cannot take credit cards directly, only PayPal Account payments (which might come from a credit card but you can't tell that)

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

> The Express Checkout button gives buyers another way to pay, and it **complements your existing payment solution**. Online shoppers appreciate the convenience and security of PayPal, where they can pay with their PayPal balance, bank account, or credit card. The following web page shows the Express Checkout button side-by-side with an existing checkout button.

The option you're trying to set doesn't even do what you're describing
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

> BUYEREMAILOPTINENABLE
>
> (Optional) Enables the buyer to provide their email address on the PayPal pages to be notified of promotions or special events.

Comment: but how i disable buyer email and password input in Express Checkout?

Comment: @MônicaR. You can't. That prompt is to log into PayPal